# Hibernate Subqueries.exists

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, criteria-api

I am having a problem with a Subqueries.exists criteria.

I have the following:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Expense.class, "mainExpense")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("group", group))
        .addOrder(Order.desc("created"));

if (all) {
    criteria.add(
            Restrictions.or(
                    Restrictions.eq("status", ExpenseStatus.PENDING),
                    Restrictions.eq("status", ExpenseStatus.COMPLETE)
            ));
} else {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", ExpenseStatus.PENDING));
}

if (user != null) {
    DetachedCriteria userSubCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserExpense.class, "userExpense")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("userExpense.primaryKey.user", user))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("userExpense.primaryKey.expense", "mainExpense"))
            .setProjection(Projections.property("userExpense.primaryKey"));
    criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(userSubCriteria));
}

return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

If I pass a null user (not using the Subqueries.exists) it works okay and returns me the valid  expense items. If I give a user if given me the following:

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of Expense.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of Expense.id

and lower in the logs:

Can not set java.lang.Integer field Expense.id to java.lang.String

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there are two problems in the query:

1. The exists subquery should have a projection returning a single column. You're using a projection that returns an embedded object.
2. You compare "userExpense.primaryKey.expense" and "mainExpense" with `Restrictions.eq()`. I don't think it's valid. You should use `Restrictions.eqProperty("userExpense.primaryKey.expense.id", "mainExpense.id")`

Comment: If seems to be from this Restrictions.eq("userExpense.primaryKey.expense", "mainExpense.id") but it doesn't work as you suggested either :-?

Comment: how does it not work? What's the exception? Do you have an ID field in Expense?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Edit your question, insert the code of the entities involved, and the complete stack trace of this exception.

Comment: Your right, it works, didn't notice that you wrote eqProperty instead of eq. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another simplified example solving the same type of problem. The criteria setup result as disjunct sets.  View - RegistryViewable (object representation), Table - DocumentType (object representation), Relation 1:n DocumentType.id : @ManyToOne RegistryViewable.typDokumentu (object representation). In entity class RegistryViewable is attribute typDokumentu DocumentType type. Attribute systemType has boolean type. Very important is clause 
`setProjection`, without it the criteria will not work.

```
            DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(RegistryViewable.class, "RegistryViewable");
    ...         
    if (EntityType.DOCUMENT.equals(searchDTO.getTypEntity())) {
                DetachedCriteria docTypeCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(DocumentType.class,
                        "DocumentType");
                docTypeCriteria
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("DocumentType" + "." + "systemType",
                                true))
                        .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("DocumentType" + "." + "id",
                                "RegistryViewable" + "." + "typDokumentu" + "."
                                        + "id"));
                docTypeCriteria.setProjection(
                        Projections.property("DocumentType" + "." + "id"));
                if (searchDTO.isSystemType()) {
                    criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(docTypeCriteria));
                } else {
                    criteria.add(Subqueries.notExists(docTypeCriteria));
                }
            }
...
        List<RegistryViewable> list = repository.findByCriteria(criteria);
```